# How can I get the usual behaviour of height on a fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a website only using HTML, CSS and Javascript, it is my first web page, and I'm getting a problem of the height on a fixed block. The "Contact us" link must open a box with the contact information in the center of the screen, so I used the fixed position, I wanted the height to work as usual, I mean only the height of it's content, but instead, it is showing 100% height of the screen, thank you, the web page is in Spanish, the link to the web site is:

http://www.bordadosyalgomas.com.ve/

Again, this is my first web page, plus I'm on the navigation bar by the time.

EDIT:
Sorry, first time asking, I didn't provide any code:

```css
div#contacts1{
 font-family: "Ubuntu Medium";
 padding: 3.5em;
 width: 50%;
 border: solid 2px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: white;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: auto;
}
div#contacts{
 width: 100%;
 height: 4000px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto;
}
div#contacts1 img{
 height: 60px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
div#contacts1 p{
 font-size: 1.3em;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding-left: 1.5em;
}
div#contacts1 p strong{
 display: block;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 margin: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0.2em;
 padding: 0;
}
div.cparador{
 height: 100px;
 margin-bottom: -1em;
 display: block;
}
div.cparador img{
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-2px 2px 4px black);
  filter: drop-shadow(-2px 2px 4px black);
 margin-left: 3em;
}
div.cparador h1{
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Bordaos y algo mas</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 @import url("index.css") screen;
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="contacts">
 </div>
 <div id="contacts1">
  <div class="cparador">
   <h1>Información de contacto:</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cparador">
   <img src="contacts/phone.png">
   <p><strong>Teléfono</strong>
   0257-2535145</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cparador">
   <img src="contacts/telegram.png">
   <p><strong>Telegram</strong>
   @bordados.ym</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cparador">
   <img src="contacts/instagram.png">
   <p><strong>Instagram</strong>
   @bordados.ym</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cparador">
   <img src="contacts/mail.png">
   <p><strong>Correo Electrónico</strong>
   bordados.ym@gmail.com</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cparador">
   <img src="contacts/whats.png">
   <p><strong>Whatsapp</strong>
   0414-5214041</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[A picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhaOF.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking, please always add the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem to your question directly (not as a link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `bottom:0;` - this combined with `top:0;` causes the div to take 100% height.

Then you can set:

```
top: 50%; // move popup down by 50% of window height
transform: translateY(-50%); // move it back by 50% of popup height
```

EDIT:
also consider adding `max-height: 100%;` to make use of `overflow: auto;` when height of the window is shorter than popup's height.

Comment: One more thing to consider in EDIT paragraph with `max-height`. Also, as my answer solves the problem, marking it as accepted will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple example of a Modal You can use, and instead of any extraa Custom CSS(Specially Height-Width) leave that simple. 
that auto height according to your contents!

link- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/